# How to get IntelliJ to recognize Play Framework *.scala.xml Templates

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, twirl

Has anyone gotten IntelliJ IDEA to recognize *.scala.xml twirl templates? HTML templates seem to get picked up by the IDE just fine and seem to be the only supported template out of box, but any other type of templates do not get picked up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem and it seems that adding a file association did the trick.

In Intellij IDEA 15 (ultimate edition):

Preferences > Editor > File Types 
Search "Play 2" and add "*.scala.xml" (expect a long indexing after that)

[image: File Types with *.scala.html added]

Comment: I don't have "Play" or "Play 2" in my file type list. It might be because I'm using Intellij IDEA Community edition, not the Ultimate edition.

Comment: @L42 Yes. I think twirl templates are only supported in ultimate edition.